# jQuery slider run code when user finishes using the slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an slider with id="slider" I currently write a log when the slider changes position. This is my code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value:40,
    min: 0,
    max: 80,
    step: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('moved'); // Run code if slider value changes
        }
    });
```

I also know how to run some code when the user releases/mouseup the handle:

```
$("#slider .ui-slider-handle").click({
    console.log('released handle');
    });
```

My problem is that with my currenty implementation I run the code everytime the user moves the handle, and sometimes he still is moving the handle and hasn't decided what is it's final position. I need to run some code when the user has finished with the slider. Am I clear on what I need to do? How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value:40,
    min: 0,
    max: 80,
    step: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('moved'); // Run code if slider value changes
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('released handle');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `stop` event: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```